# Routing error from jQuery UI tabs with ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I'm using Rails and jQuery UI to implement tabs in each user's profile. I've got it working without ajax - with ajax, things go south. I'm new to Rails and jQuery and am hoping someone can help me identify what's going wrong.

- `<div id="tabs-1">` is the first tab and it is associated with `ProfilesController` by default. That works by using an `<a href>`.
- `<div id="tabs-2">` would access `MessagesController` and load a partial `show_messages` that loads `@user.messages`.

What happens instead is that when I click "Messages" I get an ActionController::Routing error in Profiles#show.

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"messages", :id=>[#<Message id: 3, user_id: 2,...>, #<Message id: 4, user_id: 2,...">]}
```

My code is below:

**application.js:**

```
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
        ajaxOptions: {
            error: function( xhr, status, index, anchor ) {
                $( anchor.hash ).html(
                    "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
                    "If this wouldn't be a demo." );
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**My profile `show.html.erb`:**

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul id="infoContainer">
        <li><a href="#tabs-1"></a></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Messages", message_path(@user.messages) %></a></li>
    <ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
    </div>
</div>
```

**My `_show_messages` partial in MessagesController:**

```
<div id="tabs-2">
    <% for 'message' in @user.messages %>
        <div class="message">
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

in show.html.erb message_path(@users.messages) is wrong. Try messages_path which should point to the index action of the messages controllr. Here I am assuming you are using the standard Rails convection for messages routes.